# PHP7 クラス内の関数呼び出し

Tags: php

「PHP 5.6.11」で動作していた以下のようなソースが「PHP 7.1.0-dev」 で動作しなくなっていました。
※switch文の「return AAAA::$z[0]($x, $y, $z);」で「Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: AAAA::$z in test.php:21」と表示されます。
「return call_user_func_array( array('AAAA', $z[0]), array(&$x,$y,$z) );」　と書き換えれば動作することを確認はしていますが、
PHP7にバージョンアップにするにあたって、違う点などを調べたのですが、英語が苦手なのもあって、この変更点に関する記述がわかりませんでした。
どなたがご存知でしたら、参考URLなど教えていただけませんでしょうか？

```
class AAAA {
 static function caller(&$x, $y, $z)
 {
  switch($z[0])
  {
    case 'caller':
      return 0;
    case 'abc':
      return AAAA::aaa($x, $y, $z);
    case 'def':
      return AAAA::bbb($x, $y, $z);
    default:
      if( strlen($z[0]) )
      {
        return AAAA::$z[0]($x, $y, $z);
      }
      else { return 0; }
  }
 }

 static function aaa(&$x, $y, $z)
 {
   return $x[0] + $y[0];
 }

 static function bbb(&$x, $y, $z)
 {
   return $x[1] + $y[1];
 }

 static function func1(&$x, $y, $z)
 {
   $a = $x[0] + $z[1];
   $b = $y[0] * $z[1];
   return $a * $b;
 }

 static function func2(&$x, $y, $z)
 {
   $a = $x[1] + $z[2];
   $b = $y[1] * $z[3];
   return $a * $b;
 }
}

$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(5,6,7,8);
$c = array('func2', 3,4,5);
$rec = AAAA::caller($a, $b, $c);
var_dump($rec);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

その挙動の違いは、パーサーの仕様変更によるものです。

`AAAA::$z[0]()` と書いた場合、これまでのPHPでは `$z[0]` を優先して解釈していました。

1. まず `$z[0]` を評価する
2. その名前の静的メソッドをクラス `AAAA` から探して呼び出す

これが PHP7 では左結合、つまり `AAAA::$z` を優先するようになりました。

1. まず `AAAA::$z` を評価する
2. その最初の要素 `[0]` を取り出す
3. その名前の関数を探して呼び出す

このため、「静的プロパティ `AAAA::$z` が見つからない」というエラーが出ています。

PHP 5.5.6 での例 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uzNOlxho3XMslK3R
PHP 7.1.0-dev での例 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fd7HAW5kaOGHyLah

`$z[0]` を波括弧で囲んで `AAAA::{$z[0]}()` とすることで、これまでの挙動を再現できます。

詳しくはマニュアルの移行ガイドをご覧ください。

- [PHP: PHP 5.6.x から PHP 7.0.x への移行 - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ja/migration70.php)
- 同、「下位互換性のない変更点」より[「変数の取り扱いの変更」](http://php.net/manual/ja/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
まだまだ、調べ方が足りなかったようです。